# Multiple errors in a BookStore program

Tags: java, arrays, spring, performance

Having an issue with the program and im getting multiple errors

```
myBkStore.sellBook(title, y);
```

```
 myBkStore.addNewBook(book);
```

```
 if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
```

before the breaking of case 2 and string bt and public class boolean myBookStore.inStock. how do i solve this issue an advice with improvise syntax would be much more helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyBookstore {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bookstore myBkStore = new Bookstore();


    int y = 0;
    int user_choice = 2;
    boolean quit = false;

    do {
        //display menu to user
        //ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Add a book to the stock");
        System.out.println("2) Sell a book in stock");
        System.out.println("3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
        System.out.println("4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
        System.out.println("5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore");
        System.out.println("6) Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-6]: ");
        user_choice = s.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter a book title");


                    String bt = s.next();           //stores title of book user enters in

                    if (myBkStore.inStock(title, y))
                    {
                        System.out.println("How many more to add to the stock");
                        y = s.nextInt();
                        myBkStore.addBookQuantity(bt, y);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter the amount of pages of the book: ");
                        int pages = s.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter the price of the book: ");
                        double price = s.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter the quantity to add: ");
                        int quant = s.nextInt();
                        //myBkStore.Book(bt, pages, price, quant);
                        myBkStore.addNewBook(book);
                    } 


                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter book title to buy: ");
                    String bookT = s.next();
                    myBkStore.sellBook(title, y);
                    break;
            case 3: myBkStore.listTitles();
                    break;
            case 4: myBkStore.listBooks();
                    break;
            case 5: myBkStore.getIncome();
                    break;
            case 6: System.out.println("Thanks for coming");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            default: System.out.println("\nInvalid Choice");
        }
}
while (!quit);
}

static class Bookstore {
private Book[] books; // all the books in this bookstore
private int totalBooks; // the number of books in this bookstore
    private double grossIncome; //the gross income of the bookstore (will be incremented when books are sold)

// Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesn’t contain any accounts.
public Bookstore() {
    books = new Book[100];
    totalBooks = 0;
    grossIncome = 0;
    }

// Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance given as parameters
// and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account into the account list
// of the Bank calling object.
public void addNewBook(Book b) {
    if(totalBooks < books.length) {
        books[totalBooks] = b;
        totalBooks++;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nSorry, cannot add book to stock.");
    }


}


public void addBookQuantity(String title, int quantity) {
    for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
        if (title == books[i].getTitle()  ) {
            books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
            System.out.println("Quantity added successfully");
            return;
        }
    }

    /*int i;

    for (i = 0; i < totalbooks; i++)
    {
        if((books[i].getTitle()).equals(title))
        {
            books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
            return;
        }
    }*/


}

public boolean inStock (String title, int quantity) {
    for (int i =0; i<totalBooks; i++) {
            if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {
                if (quantity <= books[i].getQuantity()) {return true;}
                else {return false;}
            }
        }
    return false;

}

public boolean sellBook(String title, int quantity){
    int i;

        boolean sellflag=false;

        // Checks to see if the books are in stock.

        boolean retval = inStock(title, quantity);

        // If so, completes the sale.

        if (retval) {

          for (i=0; i<totalBooks && !sellflag; i++) {

            if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {

              books[i].subtractQuantity(quantity);

              grossIncome += (books[i].getPrice()) * quantity;

              sellflag = true;

            }

          } // for

        } // if

        return retval;

      } // sellBook






public void listTitles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(books[i].getTitle());
    }

}

public void listBooks()
{
    int i;

    System.out.println("\nList of Books\n======");
    for (i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(books[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public double getIncome()
{
    return grossIncome;
}





}





  static class Book{

       private String title;
       private int numOfPages;
       private double price;
       private int quantity;
       private Book book;

       public String toString(){
           return "Title: " + title + "\nNumber of pages: " + numOfPages + "\nPrice:" + price +"\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\n";


       }


       public Book book(String thetitle, int pages, double cost, int num){
         /*title = thetitle;
         numOfPages = pages;
         price = cost;
         quantity = num;*/
         return book;

       }

       public String getTitle(){
         return title;
       }

       public double getPrice(){
         return price;
       }

       public int getQuantity(){
         return quantity;
       }

       public void addQuantity(int amount){
            quantity = quantity + amount;

    }
    public void subtractQuantity(int amount)
    {
          System.out.println("Amount to buy");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        quantity = s.nextInt();
        quantity = quantity - amount;   
    }

}//end of class
}
```

Comment: What are you doing? Do you know how to use a switch case structure?

Comment: My posted answer addresses the one problem. However, there are bound to be other issues with your code. I didn't debug your code.

Comment: You need to post code that at least compiles. Your question it's probably going to get closed because of this.

Comment: *im getting multiple errors* Which errors are you getting? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions about errors are fine here, but you indispensably need to be very specific about which errors. Paste the error messages into your question.

Comment: Add this code line: `Book book = new Book();` beneath the  code line `Bookstore myBkStore = new Bookstore();`. Once that is done, change `title` to `book.title`.

Answer (score 1):

I was feeling generous, so I fixed your code. All compiling errors are gone and fixed a few logic errors as well.

```
public class MyBookstore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Bookstore myBkStore = new Bookstore();

        int y = 0;
        int user_choice = 2;
        boolean quit = false;

        do {
            // display menu to user
            // ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1) Add a book to the stock");
            System.out.println("2) Sell a book in stock");
            System.out.println("3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
            System.out.println("4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)");
            System.out.println("5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore");
            System.out.println("6) Quit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter choice [1-6]: ");
            user_choice = s.nextInt();
            s.nextLine(); // THIS IS NEEDED TO MOVE THE SCANNER TO THE NEXT LINE BEFORE GETTING THE TITLE.
            switch (user_choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter a book title: ");
                String bt = s.nextLine(); // stores title of book user enters in
                if (myBkStore.inStock(bt)) {
                    System.out.print("How many more to add to the stock: ");
                    y = s.nextInt();
                    myBkStore.addBookQuantity(bt, y);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter the amount of pages of the book: ");
                    int pages = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the price of the book: ");
                    double price = s.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter the quantity to add: ");
                    int quant = s.nextInt();
                    // myBkStore.Book(bt, pages, price, quant);
                    myBkStore.addNewBook(new Book(bt, pages, price, quant));
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter book title to buy: ");
                String bookT = s.nextLine();
                myBkStore.sellBook(bookT);
                break;
            case 3:
                myBkStore.listTitles();
                break;
            case 4:
                myBkStore.listBooks();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("\nStore Gross income: " +  myBkStore.getIncome());
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Thanks for coming");
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Choice");
            }
        } while (!quit);
        s.close();
    }

    static class Bookstore {
        private Book[] books; // all the books in this bookstore
        private int totalBooks; // the number of books in this bookstore
        private double grossIncome; // the gross income of the bookstore (will be incremented when books are sold)

        // Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesn’t contain any accounts.
        public Bookstore() {
            books = new Book[100];
            totalBooks = 0;
            grossIncome = 0;
        }

        // Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance
        // given as parameters
        // and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account
        // into the account list
        // of the Bank calling object.
        public void addNewBook(Book b) {
            if (totalBooks < books.length) {
                books[totalBooks] = b;
                totalBooks++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nSorry, cannot add book to stock.");
            }
        }

        public void addBookQuantity(String title, int quantity) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {
                if (title == books[i].getTitle()) {
                    books[i].addQuantity(quantity);
                    System.out.println("Quantity added successfully");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean inStock(String title) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {
                if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {
                    if ( books[i].getQuantity() > 0) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean sellBook(String title) {
            int i;
            boolean sellflag = false;

            // Checks to see if the books are in stock.
            boolean retval = inStock(title);

            // If so, completes the sale.
            if (retval) {
                for (i = 0; i < totalBooks && !sellflag; i++) {
                    if (title.equals(books[i].getTitle())) {
                        int quantity = books[i].subtractQuantity();
                        grossIncome += (books[i].getPrice()) * quantity;
                        sellflag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retval;
        }

        public void listTitles() {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {
                System.out.println(books[i].getTitle());
            }
        }

        public void listBooks() {
            int i;

            System.out.println("\nList of Books\n======");
            for (i = 0; i < totalBooks; i++) {
                System.out.println(books[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        public double getIncome() {
            return grossIncome;
        }
    }

    private static class Book {

        private String title;
        private int numOfPages;
        private double price;
        private int quantity;

        public String toString() {
            return "Title: " + title + "\nNumber of pages: " + numOfPages + "\nPrice:" + price + "\nQuantity: "
                    + quantity + "\n";
        }

        public Book(String thetitle, int pages, double cost, int num) {
            title = thetitle;
            numOfPages = pages;
            price = cost;
            quantity = num;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void addQuantity(int amount) {
            quantity = quantity + amount;

        }

        public int subtractQuantity() {
            System.out.println("Amount to buy");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int amount = s.nextInt();
            quantity = quantity - amount;
            return amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 1
Enter a book title: Effective Java
Enter the amount of pages of the book: 
300
Enter the price of the book: 
29.99
Enter the quantity to add: 
10

1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 1
Enter a book title: Learn Python
Enter the amount of pages of the book: 
100
Enter the price of the book: 
10.00
Enter the quantity to add: 
5

1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 2
Enter book title to buy: 
Effective Java
Amount to buy
1

1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 3
Effective Java
Learn Python

1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 4

List of Books
======
Title: Effective Java
Number of pages: 300
Price:29.99
Quantity: 9

Title: Learn Python
Number of pages: 100
Price:10.0
Quantity: 5



1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 5

Store Gross income: 29.99

1) Add a book to the stock
2) Sell a book in stock
3) List the titles of all the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
4) List all the information about the books in stock (in the Bookstore object)
5) Print out the gross income of the bookstore
6) Quit

Enter choice [1-6]: 6
Thanks for coming
```

Your main issue was related to the use of `Scanner`.

1. For titles, since they can have more than one word (separated with spaces), you needed to use `Scanner#nextLine()` rather than `Scanner#next()`. Because of that,
2. When you were getting the numeric input for the main menu, you needed to consume the line. Calling `Scanner#nextInt()` doesn't consume the line. Therefore, you need to call `Scanner#nextLine()` before the next prompt so that the scanner is moved to the next line to get the next inputted value.